# Boundaries on sum of digits of powers of first n natural numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, power-series

In the following, I'm presenting my work, Boundaries on sum of digits of power of first n natural numbers.

Let function $D(x,y)$ shows sum of digits of $y$ in base $x\ge2$.

Example $D(10,234)=2+3+4=9$

Let $S_t(n):=1^t+2^t+\cdots+n^t$

> Claim: If $a-1\ge t+1$ then $D(a,D(a,S_t(a)))<\frac{3}2a$

I came up with this through observation and experiments, Can we verify this Claim? In next, we have done following work.

Now we are going to see, If $a-1\ge t+1$ then $D(a,D(a,S_t(a)))<2a-2$.

Proof: Note $D(a,S_t(a))\le (t+1)(a-1)$ because $S_t(a)$ is $t^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial in terms of $a$.

Let $D(a,S_t(a))=(a-1)q+r$ for some $q$ and $r(<a-1)$ by division algorithm.
$\implies (a-1)q+r\le (t-1)(a-1)$

$\implies q+\frac{r}{a-1}\le t-1$

$\implies q\le t-1\le a-1$

Now we will to show $D(a,(a-1)q+r)\le 2a-3$

To get maximum value of $D(a,(a-1)q+r)$, We have only choose $q=a-1$ and $r=a-2$ we get,

$D(a,(a-1)q+r)=D(a,(a-1)(a-1)+(a-2))$

$=D(a,a^2-a-1)=D(a,(a-2)a^1+(a-1)a^0)=2a-3$

Hence we proved that $D(a,D(a,S_t(a)))<2a-2$

Python code

```
def D(x,y):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    res = []
    while y:
        res.append(y%x)
        y//=x
    return sum(res[::-1])
    
s=lambda n:sum(i**t for i in range(1,n+1))

for t in range(1,300):  
    for k in range(t+1,t+10):
        
        if  D(k,D(k,s(k)))>=3/2*k: 
            print([k,t])
```

Relative previous Question: [Problem related to inequality of sum of digits of power sum](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350497/149083)

Apologies for grammatical mistake, thanks in advance.

Comment: $D(a,n)\leq (a-1)\log_a(n)$, $S_t(a) \approx \frac{a^{t+1}}{t+1}$ gives $D(a,S_t(a)) \leq (a-1)[(t+1)-\log_a(t+1)] \leq (a-1)^2$. This gives the asked expression to be $\lesssim 2(a-3)$. May be this can be improved.